# Is it possible for C++ to write a template that takes a Container as parameter?

Tags: c++11, c++14

I would try to make my point clear with an example:

We have

```
template <class RandomAccessIterator>
void sort (RandomAccessIterator first, RandomAccessIterator last);
```

But I'm thinking if it is ok to make it more convenient:

```
template <typename T> void sort(std::vector<T>& container) {
    std::sort( container.begin(), container.end() );
}
template <typename T> void sort(std::list<T>& container);
template <typename T> void sort(std::array<T>& container);
//e.t.c
```

You know there are many container types, it is possible to code once for all the container types?

```
void sort(ContainerType<ElementType> &container); 
//and container should have begin() and end() methods,
//otherwise the compiler would warn me.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are talking about *concepts* in C++. The idea is discussed for a long time for now, but they are still not in the standard. [See here](http://isocpp.org/blog/2013/02/concepts-lite-constraining-templates-with-predicates-andrew-sutton-bjarne-s):

```
template<Sortable Cont>
void sort(Cont& container);
```

The work is close to the end for now, several experimental implementations are [already](http://concepts.axiomatics.org/~ans/) [available](http://www.generic-programming.org/software/ConceptClang/papers/wgp06v-voufo.pdf), and we expect them to hit C++17, hopefully. The nicest thing about concepts is their straightforward error messages:

```
list<int> lst = ...;   // oops, bidirectional iterators
sort(lst);             // error: 'T' is not a/an 'Sortable' type
```

In modern compilers, errors related to templatized code are very confusing. Compare with this example, compiled with Visual Studio 2013:

```
std::list<int> l;
std::sort(l.begin(), l.end());
// error C2784: 'unknown-type std::operator -(std::move_iterator<_RanIt> &,const std::move_iterator<_RanIt2> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'std::move_iterator<_RanIt> &' from 'std::_List_iterator<std::_List_val<std::_List_simple_types<int>>>'
// error C2784: 'unknown-type std::operator -(const std::reverse_iterator<_RanIt> &,const std::reverse_iterator<_RanIt2> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const std::reverse_iterator<_RanIt> &' from 'std::_List_iterator<std::_List_val<std::_List_simple_types<int>>>'
// error C2784: 'unknown-type std::operator -(const std::_Revranit<_RanIt,_Base> &,const std::_Revranit<_RanIt2,_Base2> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const std::_Revranit<_RanIt,_Base> &' from 'std::_List_iterator<std::_List_val<std::_List_simple_types<int>>>'
```

There is even a tag on SO: [c++-concepts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2B%2B-concepts).

Answer (score 1):

Its easy to write a sort function that works for any container. Just write:

```
template<class C>
void sort(C& container) {
    std::sort( container.begin(), container.end() );
}
```

However, if you want your sort function to be picked ONLY for containers, it becomes a little bit more difficult: As concepts are not yet available, you have to write your own type trait for all containers and use SFINAE.

---

Edit: Come to think of it, as any class with a random access iterator is probably a container anyway, it should be enough to write the following (without the need for a container trait):

```
#include <type_traits>
template<class C>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<typename std::iterator_traits<typename C::iterator>::iterator_category, std::random_access_iterator_tag>{}>::type
sort(C& container) {
    std::sort( container.begin(), container.end() );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iterator>
#include <utility>
#include <type_traits>

namespace detail
{
    using std::begin;    
    template <typename T, typename = void>
    struct has_begin : std::false_type {};
    template <typename T>
    struct has_begin<T, decltype(void(begin(std::declval<T&>())))> : std::true_type {};

    using std::end;
    template <typename T, typename = void>
    struct has_end : std::false_type {};
    template <typename T>
    struct has_end<T, decltype(void(end(std::declval<T&>())))> : std::true_type {};
}

template <typename T> using has_begin = detail::has_begin<T>;
template <typename T> using has_end = detail::has_end<T>;
```

*Usage:*

```
template <typename ContainerType>
void sort(ContainerType& container)
{
    static_assert(has_begin<ContainerType>{} && has_end<ContainerType>{},
                  "Invalid container type");
}
```

*Tests:*

```
#include <vector>
#include <list>

namespace X
{
    struct A {};        
    A* begin(A&) { return {}; }
    A* end(A&) { return {}; }
}

struct B {};

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v; sort(v);  // OK
    std::list<int> l; sort(l);    // OK
    X::A a; sort(a);              // OK
    int arr[3]{}; sort(arr);      // OK
    B b; sort(b);                 // error: Invalid container type
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e85b7e92a117678b)

Comment: if OP wraps `std::sort()` in this sort(), then calling `sort()` with `std::list` will cause compilation error. Your demo only goes till checking for the invoking of `begin()` and `end()` does address if `std::sort()` is callable by the container that's passed or not.

Comment: @Jagannath the question is clearly about `begin` and `end` calls, "*container should have begin() and end() methods, otherwise the compiler would warn me.*"

Answer (score 0):

**At the time of answering this question**, MikeMB's answer gives the approach but doesn't compile. But here is my attempt. A much lesser complicated approach. You will have to overload SortHelper to accept comparator as well.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <list>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>


template<typename C>
void SortHelper(C& container, std::random_access_iterator_tag)
{
    std::sort(std::begin(container), std::end(container));
}

template<typename C>
void SortHelper(C& container, std::bidirectional_iterator_tag)
{
    container.sort();
}



template<class C>
void sort(C& container)
{
    SortHelper(container, typename std::iterator_traits<typename C::iterator>::iterator_category());
}


int main()
{
    std::vector<int> ints1 { 3, 2, 1 };
    std::list<int> ints2 { 3, 2, 1 };

    sort(ints1);
    sort(ints2);

    std::cout << "printing ints1\n";
    for (auto e : ints1 ) { std::cout << e << "\n" ; }
    std::cout << "printing ints2\n";
    for (auto e : ints2 ) { std::cout << e << "\n" ; }

}
```

***Output***

printing ints1
1
2
3
printing ints2
1
2
3